# Tor Selenium works only in incognito mode Windows Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

This code runs the connection via Tor. You need to have Tor browser running **beforehand** to run this code successfully. However, that happens only when running an incognito window and the user profile is *not* loaded. When I remove that option it gets connected via my ISP. Anyway around this? To connect via Tor and have my user profile loaded. Also, if there is a window already open, it will not open the browser, because the User Data is already in use.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


tor_proxy = "127.0.0.1:9150"

chrome_options = Options()


chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors') 
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://%s' % tor_proxy)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.wtfismyip.com')
```

**INFO**
I think that the Tor browser's purpose would be defeated if it allowed loading signed-in profiles on *subsequent* runs. It is all about anonymity, if someone could just confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

TO open tor you can use :

https://github.com/webfp/tor-browser-selenium

**Steps:**

**First goto tor browser and type about:profiles :**

[image]

**THen open Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor folder :**

There you can see a tor.exe file double click that :

[image]

**Then run below code**

```
from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver
import time
driver= TorBrowserDriver(executable_path=r"C:\Users\prave\Downloads\travelBA\geckodriver.exe", tbb_fx_binary_path=r'C:\Users\prave\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe', tbb_profile_path=r'C:\Users\prave\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default')
driver.get('check.torproject.org')
time.sleep(100000)
```

**Note:** if you get a error saying filenotfound blabla/browser create an empty folder named broser at that location

**Ignore below commands :**

Could you try the below code , the right way to set sock proxy

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

PROXY = "127.0.0.1:9150"
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": PROXY,
    "ftpProxy": PROXY,
    "sslProxy": PROXY,
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",
    "socksProxy": PROXY,
    "socksVersion":5

}

webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['acceptSslCerts'] = True
chrome_options=Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument(
    r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\prave\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=r'C:\Users\prave\Downloads\travelBA\chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.wtfismyip.com')

time.sleep(10000)
```

Comment: caps['proxy']['proxyType'] = caps['proxy']['proxyType'].lower()
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: @AbhishekRai could you try the updated code

Comment: how are you getting the tor proxy ? so that i can try myself

Comment: tor browser is running. Without that won't work.

Comment: No, Still connects via my ISP.

Comment: @AbhishekRai how are you getting the PROXY address from ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225605/discussion-between-abhishek-rai-and-pdhide).

Comment: @AbhishekRai Added the answer

Comment: tbselenium doesn't work on windows as  far as I know..You sure about this?

Comment: @AbhishekRai just tried and worked :) the way is to double click the tor.exe file

Comment: wait..I will try this and get back to you

Comment: where did you save tbselenium? I am using pycharm.

Comment: Pip installed I am not sure how to pip install in pycharm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225611/discussion-between-pdhide-and-abhishek-rai).